# MS Access Security Warnings after changing attributes via CreateFileA OPEN_EXISTING parameter

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, winapi

I have a code which is shown below, the main point is to make some changes in the .accdb file, saving the existing CreationTime, LastAccessTime and LastWriteTime attributes of the file.

Everything works perfectly, but I have faced this problem:
The original MS access projects (thousands of .accdb files) contain VBA Macros. The standart policy is: "Disable all macros with notification". So once the user has clicked the button, the file saves his preference (for this file only) - and this is fine.

But after I make changes to the file by the following script, it resets the security settings for this exact file and the yellow "Security Warning" appears next time the user opens the database (all the Macros and active content is the same, nothing new!).

The problem is: I have thousands of accdb files. I need to make small changes, but to save the existing attributes. 
And when users will open these files, there shouldn't be any new Security Alert bar.

I can, but I don't want to:

- change Security Settings for Active content
- make this folder a Trusted folder
- any other Security Settings changes, like Regedit and so on.

I do NOT add any Macros or Active content, the message appears because some settings after using CreateFileA were changed, I guess. 
(for example, if I manually rename the file, MS Access thinks that it is another file - and shows the Security bar - and that is right; but why does it show up after changing file attributes?)

Thanks! 
P.S. We are using MS Access 2016.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Const GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000, GENERIC_READ = &H80000000, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = &H80, OPEN_EXISTING = 3

Public Type FileTime:  dwLowDateTime As Long:  dwHighDateTime As Long: End Type

Public Type SYSTEMTIME:  wYear As Integer:  wMonth As Integer:  wDayOfWeek As Integer:  wDay As Integer:  wHour As Integer:  wMinute As Integer:  wSecond As Integer:  wMilliseconds As Integer: End Type

Declare Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileA" (ByVal lpFilename As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal dwShareMode As Long, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long

Declare Function SetFileTime Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpCreationTime As FileTime, lpLastAccessTime As FileTime, lpLastWriteTime As FileTime) As Long

Declare Function GetFileTime Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpCreationTime As FileTime, lpLastAccessTime As FileTime, lpLastWriteTime As FileTime) As Long

Declare Function SystemTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long

Declare Function LocalFileTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpFileTime As FileTime, lpLocalFileTime As FileTime) As Long

Declare Function FileTimeToSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (lpFileTime As FileTime, lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Long

Declare Function FileTimeToLocalFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpLocalFileTime As FileTime, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long

Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Public GlobCreationDate As Date, GlobLastAccess As Date, GlobLastWrite As Date

Public FileAddress As String



Function DTtoFT(ByVal DT As Date) As FileTime 'DateTimeToFileTime
Dim ST As SYSTEMTIME, lTime As FileTime
ST.wYear = Year(DT): ST.wMonth = Month(DT): ST.wDay = Day(DT): ST.wHour = Hour(DT): ST.wMinute = Minute(DT): ST.wSecond = Second(DT)
SystemTimeToFileTime ST, lTime
LocalFileTimeToFileTime lTime, DTtoFT
End Function

Function FTtoDT(FT As FileTime) As Date 'FileTimeToDateTime
Dim lTime As FileTime, ST As SYSTEMTIME
FileTimeToLocalFileTime FT, lTime
FileTimeToSystemTime lTime, ST
FTtoDT = DateSerial(ST.wYear, ST.wMonth, ST.wDay) + TimeSerial(ST.wHour, ST.wMinute, ST.wSecond)
End Function


Sub GetFTime(fName As String, Creation As Date, LastAccess As Date, LastWrite As Date)
Dim hFile As Long, ct As FileTime, at As FileTime, wt As FileTime
hFile = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
GetFileTime hFile, ct, at, wt
CloseHandle hFile
Creation = FTtoDT(ct): LastAccess = FTtoDT(at): LastWrite = FTtoDT(wt)
GlobCreationDate = FTtoDT(ct): GlobLastAccess = FTtoDT(at): GlobLastWrite = FTtoDT(wt)
End Sub

Sub SetFTime(fName As String, Optional Creation As Date = -657434, Optional LastAccess As Date = -657434, Optional LastWrite As Date = -657434)
Dim hFile As Long, ct As Date, at As Date, wt As Date

If Creation = -657434 Or LastAccess = -657434 Or LastWrite = -657434 Then
  GetFTime fName, ct, at, wt
  If Creation = -657434 Then Creation = ct
  If LastAccess = -657434 Then LastAccess = at
  If LastWrite = -657434 Then LastWrite = wt
End If

hFile = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
SetFileTime hFile, DTtoFT(Creation), DTtoFT(LastAccess), DTtoFT(LastWrite)
CloseHandle hFile
End Sub




Sub SetChanges()
Dim T1 As Date, T2 As Date, T3 As Date, T4 As Date, T5 As Date, T6 As Date
Dim cn As Object, strQuery As String
Dim strPathToDB As String

FileAddress = "D:\Projects\DB1.accdb"

GetFTime FileAddress, T1, T2, T3


'some code right here


SetFTime FileAddress, T1, T2, T3


'
End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I remember Windows will store a checksum aside the file approval in the registry. So maybe one or more dates which you change belong to this checksum, causing the approval being invalid. Maybe you should use Trusted Locations (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7EE1CDC2-483E-4CBB-BCB3-4E7C67147FB4) instead?

Comment: Access also writes info to the file, so - I guess - you will have to do what you "can, but [I] don't want to". As you are in control of the full process, your first method "change Security Settings for Active content" appears harmless to me, as you can reset it when done.

Comment: @Unhandled Exception Thank you, you were right! Seems, it is using Creation Date, File Location and File Name as a trigger - I do not know exactly if they are used combined as a checksum or something, but if you change any of these attributes, it causes the approval being invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, guys, I've found the solution, so maybe this would help someone.

The reason MS Access was showing Security Warnings is because the script was technically changing the creation date, even though it was the same date.

So now I can state that MS Access is using Creation Date, File Location and File Name as a trigger, I do not know exactly if they are used combined as a checksum or something, but if you change any of these attributes, the Access thinks it could be a different file I guess.

I looked up through the MS Windows API, and found this:

> A function using the FILETIME structure can allow for values outside of zero or positive values typically specified by the dwLowDateTime and dwHighDateTime members. For example, the SetFileTime function uses 0xFFFFFFFF to specify that a file's previous access time should be preserved.

So I changed the code a little bit:

```
Option Explicit
Public Const GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000, GENERIC_READ = &H80000000, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = &H80, OPEN_EXISTING = 3
Public Type FileTime:  dwLowDateTime As Long:  dwHighDateTime As Long: End Type
Public Type SYSTEMTIME:  wYear As Integer:  wMonth As Integer:  wDayOfWeek As Integer:  wDay As Integer:  wHour As Integer:  wMinute As Integer:  wSecond As Integer:  wMilliseconds As Integer: End Type
Declare Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileA" (ByVal lpFilename As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal dwShareMode As Long, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long
Declare Function SetFileTime Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpCreationTime As FileTime, lpLastAccessTime As FileTime, lpLastWriteTime As FileTime) As Long
Declare Function GetFileTime Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpCreationTime As FileTime, lpLastAccessTime As FileTime, lpLastWriteTime As FileTime) As Long
Declare Function SystemTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long
Declare Function LocalFileTimeToFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpFileTime As FileTime, lpLocalFileTime As FileTime) As Long
Declare Function FileTimeToSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (lpFileTime As FileTime, lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Long
Declare Function FileTimeToLocalFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpLocalFileTime As FileTime, lpFileTime As FileTime) As Long
Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Public GlobCreationDate As Date, GlobLastAccess As Date, GlobLastWrite As Date
Public FileAddress As String

Function DTtoFT(ByVal DT As Date) As FileTime 
Dim ST As SYSTEMTIME, lTime As FileTime
ST.wYear = Year(DT): ST.wMonth = Month(DT): ST.wDay = Day(DT): ST.wHour = Hour(DT): ST.wMinute = Minute(DT): ST.wSecond = Second(DT)
SystemTimeToFileTime ST, lTime
LocalFileTimeToFileTime lTime, DTtoFT
End Function

Function FTtoDT(FT As FileTime) As Date 
Dim lTime As FileTime, ST As SYSTEMTIME
FileTimeToLocalFileTime FT, lTime
FileTimeToSystemTime lTime, ST
FTtoDT = DateSerial(ST.wYear, ST.wMonth, ST.wDay) + TimeSerial(ST.wHour, ST.wMinute, ST.wSecond)
End Function

Sub GetFTime(fName As String, Creation As Date, LastAccess As Date, LastWrite As Date)
Dim hFile As Long, ct As FileTime, at As FileTime, wt As FileTime
hFile = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
GetFileTime hFile, ct, at, wt
CloseHandle hFile
Creation = FTtoDT(ct): LastAccess = FTtoDT(at): LastWrite = FTtoDT(wt)
GlobCreationDate = FTtoDT(ct): GlobLastAccess = FTtoDT(at): GlobLastWrite = FTtoDT(wt)
End Sub



Sub SetFTime(fName As String, Optional Creation As Date = -657434, Optional LastAccess As Date = -657434, Optional LastWrite As Date = -657434)
Dim hFile As Long, ct As Date, at As Date, wt As Date
Dim CreateF As FileTime, AccessF As FileTime

If Creation = -657434 Or LastAccess = -657434 Or LastWrite = -657434 Then
  GetFTime fName, ct, at, wt
  If Creation = -657434 Then Creation = ct
  If LastAccess = -657434 Then LastAccess = at
  If LastWrite = -657434 Then LastWrite = wt
End If

CreateF.dwLowDateTime = 0: CreateF.dwHighDateTime = 0
AccessF.dwLowDateTime = 0: AccessF.dwLowDateTime = 0

hFile = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
SetFileTime hFile, CreateF, AccessF, DTtoFT(LastWrite)
CloseHandle hFile
End Sub



Sub SetChanges()
Dim T1 As Date, T2 As Date, T3 As Date
Dim cn As Object, strQuery As String
Dim strPathToDB As String

FileAddress = "D:\Projects\DB1.accdb"

GetFTime FileAddress, T1, T2, T3

'some code right here'

SetFTime FileAddress, T1, T2, T3

End Sub
```

How it works: now the script doesn't make any changes to CreationTime and LastAccessTime and uses file's previous attributes. But it changes the LastWriteTime right after some code is executed. And - finally - it works without resetting the security for the final user.